# The value inputed in editext is changing to the last value inputed when the cursor is not in focus

Tags: android

I'm having problem about getting the last value of the text in editText when it has already not in focus.When i input a value for the first time and when it has not in focus i get the last value i inputed but for the second time and so on whenever i change the iputed value inside editText when it is not in focus it should get the value i inputed but it is changing to the last value i inputed but when saving to database it saves the value that i really inputed that tine.I know It's hard to understand what i'm saying here but i hope you can help me please.. here's my code

```
package com.functions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.senditem.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model>  {


 private final List<Model> list;


 String adapter;
    private final Activity context;
    private final int id;
    int listPosition;
    public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list, int id){
        super(context, R.layout.userproduct, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.id = id;
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        protected TextView text;
        EditText quantity;
        protected TextView amount;
        TextView ext;
        Spinner uom;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        listPosition = position;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.userproduct, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(); 
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.text.setFocusable(true);
            viewHolder.quantity = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputQty);
            viewHolder.amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputAmt);
            viewHolder.uom = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputUom);
            viewHolder.ext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputTamt);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.label, viewHolder.text);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.inputQty, viewHolder.quantity);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.inputAmt, viewHolder.amount);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.inputTamt, viewHolder.ext);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.inputUom, viewHolder.uom);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        SqliteHelper db = new SqliteHelper(context);
        viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.quantity.setId(position);
        viewHolder.amount.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getAmt()));
        viewHolder.amount.setId(position);
        viewHolder.ext.setId(position);    
        viewHolder.uom.setId(position);
        viewHolder.text.setId(position);
        String data = db.getAllDetails(id, list.get(position).getitemId());
        String data2 = db.getExt(id,list.get(position).getitemId());
        if(data==null)
        {
            viewHolder.quantity.setText(list.get(position).quantity);       
        }
        else{
            viewHolder.quantity.setText(data);
        }
        if(data2==null)
        {
            viewHolder.ext.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).ext));
        }
        else{
            viewHolder.ext.setText(data2);
        }
        viewHolder.quantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (!hasFocus){
                        final int position = v.getId();
                        final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                        list.get(position).quantity = Caption.getText().toString();              

                    }
                }
            });

        viewHolder.ext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                        final int position = v.getId();
                        final TextView Caption = (TextView) v;    


               list.get(position).ext = (float) Integer.parseInt((Caption.getText().toString()));



                }
            }
        });

        List<Model> uomlist = (List<Model>) 

db.selectUom(list.get(position).getitemId());

        List<String> myuom = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int j=0;j<uomlist.size();j++){
            myuom.add(uomlist.get(j).getUom());
        }




ArrayAdapter<String> uomadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,myuom);
    uomadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    viewHolder.uom.setAdapter(uomadapter);

    return convertView;



    }





}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model>  {

    private final List<Model> list;


    String adapter;
    private final Activity context;
    private final int id;
    int listPosition;
    public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list, int id){
        super(context, R.layout.userproduct, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.id = id;
    }


    class ViewHolder{
        protected TextView text;
        EditText quantity;
        protected TextView amount;
        TextView ext;
        Spinner uom;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        listPosition = position;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.userproduct, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.text.setFocusable(true);
            viewHolder.quantity = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputQty);
            viewHolder.amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputAmt);
            viewHolder.uom = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputUom);
            viewHolder.ext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inputTamt);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        SqliteHelper db = new SqliteHelper(context);
        viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.quantity.setId(position);
        viewHolder.amount.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getAmt()));
        viewHolder.amount.setId(position);
        viewHolder.ext.setId(position);
        viewHolder.uom.setId(position);
        viewHolder.text.setId(position);
        String data = db.getAllDetails(id, list.get(position).getitemId());
        String data2 = db.getExt(id,list.get(position).getitemId());

        if(data==null)
        {
            viewHolder.quantity.setText(list.get(position).quantity);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder.quantity.setText(data);
        }
        if(data2==null)
        {
            viewHolder.ext.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).ext));
        }
        else{
            viewHolder.ext.setText(data2);
        }
        viewHolder.quantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    list.get(position).quantity = ((EditText) v).getText().toString();

                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.ext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    list.get(position).ext = (float) Integer.parseInt((((TextView) v).getText().toString()));

                }
            }
        });

        List<Model> uomlist = (List<Model>) db.selectUom(list.get(position).getitemId());
        List<String> myuom = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int j=0;j<uomlist.size();j++){
            myuom.add(uomlist.get(j).getUom());
        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> uomadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,myuom);
        uomadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        viewHolder.uom.setAdapter(uomadapter);

        return convertView;

    }
}
```